# OpenShift - Can't connect to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, openshift

I try to connect to MongoDB from my NodeJS App.

The connection is working on my local machine so it has to be a problem with my OpenShift.

In my servercode I use:

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL)
```

But I get the following error in the logs:

```
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server/server.js'
Warning: connect.session() MemoryStore is not
designed for a production environment, as it will leak
memory, and will not scale past a single process.
Express server listening on port 8080
/var/lib/openshift/57a1ec260c1e662f1c00009f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:261
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                            ^
MongoError: failed to connect to sDerver [localhost:27017] on first connect
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/57a1ec260c1e662f1c00009f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:313:35)
    at emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/57a1ec260c1e662f1c00009f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:271:12)
    at g (events.js:180:16)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/57a1ec260c1e662f1c00009f/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:180:16)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)
DEBUG: Program node server/server.js exited with code 8
```

Comment: try mongoose.connect(process.env.OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_URL + <database name>), where <database name> is actually your app name or process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME on openshift

Comment: It is not working.
It's still the same error.

Comment: it's strange that it's showing [localhost:27017].  This doesn't seem like on openshift.  none of my apps is showing as localhost. Here is an example of one: 127.9.51.130:27017.  Maybe you need to provide more code for us to be able to help you

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I actually solved it with your first comment.
So adding the 'process.env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME' did the trick. I just had a typo in my code which I found after I wrote my first comment.